# Get length of range in Python List Comprehension

Tags: python-3.x

I wonder if it is possible to get the length of the range in a list comprehension in python 3 in order to set up a conditional as such? **this code doesn't work**

```
b = [x**2 for x in range(10) if x % 2 == 0 and x > len/2]
```

Comment: If you're putting the length condition in an `if` that comes after the `for` (meaning that if the condition isn't met, the item is skipped), you should probably just shorted the `range`. If you did `range(5)` (and omitted the length check), you'd get exactly the results you want. In fact, you could do `range(0, 5, 2)` and skip the `x %2 == 0` part of the check too.

Comment: Is the real test to determine if `x` is greater than half the length, or do you just want the latter half of the `range`? That is, what do you want for `range(10, 20)`; every value is greater than half the length, so do you want to keep all of them (`x > len(therange) / 2`) or do you want to keep the latter half?

Comment: @Blckknght: Agreed (though the equivalent code would be based on `range(6, 10, 2)`, not `range(5)` or `range(0, 5, 2)`. This could be automated for arbitrary `range` caps by taking a cap of `n` and calculating the start with `n // 2 + 1 & ~1` (rounds to even, rounding up if needed).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> n = 10
>>> b = [x**2 for x in range(n) if x % 2 == 0 and x > n/2]
>>> b
[36, 64]
```

Comment: I understand all of the above comments and appreciate the responses; however, @GBR24 has answered it sufficient to my needs. I wish to utilize this logic for more complex lists than the one I provided. Thank you again for your responses. - Erik

Comment: You could mark my answer as accepted :) ... There are certainly more complex ways to do what you wanted, like `b = [x**2 for x in range(10) if x % 2 == 0 and x > len(list(range(10)))/2]`, but the principle of KISS prevails.